# Resizing inner div on resizing size of dijit.layout.BorderContainer

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a div of dojoType **dijit.layout.BorderContainer**, And i am trying to set the size of this bordercontainer dynamically with respect to size of the viewport. The html code to create the border container is

```
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" design="sidebar" gutters="true" liveSplitters="true" id="borderContainer" style="border: solid green 3px;">
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" splitter="true" region="leading" style="width: 230px; padding:2px 0px 0px 0px;">
</div>
</div>
```

I am updating the size of the border container using the following javascript code

```
var viewport    =   dojo.window.getBox(dojo.doc);
dojo.setStyle('borderContainer','height','430px');
```

but on executing the code i was able to see the size of the div of type border container to be changed, however the div inside the div of type bordercontainer is not changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to call `resize` on the widget and the widget will resize its children.

```
var viewport    =   dojo.window.getBox(dojo.doc);
var borderContainer = dijit.byId('borderContainer');

dojo.setStyle(borderContainer.domNode, 'height','430px');
borderContainer.resize();
```

**An alternative approach**

When I want the border container to take up the whole screen, I will set it's `height` and `width` to 100%.  All parent dom nodes of the border container will also need a height of 100% set (i.e. `<html>`, `<body>`, etc.)